# Visual Studio Debugger Freezing for specific solution

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code, freeze

I'm running in to an issue where my solution freezes when debugging. If I place a breakpoint at the beginning of the solution, it wont freeze and will allow me to either continue or step through just fine. With this solution however, I need it to start from a specific point in the code. When I try to start it from that specific point, it'll freeze, and the output and locals box will have a popup in each saying "Busy..". It did not have this issue a few days ago, but just started yesterday.

It only occurs to this specific solution (I can debug other solutions just fine). Using C#/.NET mostly.

Remedies I've tried: Clean/Rebuild, repair on installer, uninstall just app, uninstall app and associated files, running Release, code cleanup, upgrading/downgrading vos, placing breakpoint at beginning then jumping to next breakpoint at specified point, removing antivirus software temporarily

Running latest version of Visual Studios 19 Community at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the solution necessarily, but deemed it to be an issue with the "Locals" box that displays all your local variables and values. If I close out of this, I can continue with debugging. From further research, it seems that tool has been known to be pretty buggy.